# Primefaces call URL and get data

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to call a URL which should return me a XML file.
I want to Display this XML file.
Right now I don't know how to make the call to get the return file.
I tryied it with a `<p:commandButton process="@this" action="http://..."  value="Test" />` but I get 2 warnings.

> Warning for file: Couldn't find a Mime-Type, add a Mime-Type mapping in your web.xml
>   Warning for Ressource: Can not be found or operated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use for example restfull client to get your xml and parse it.

Here's your content of actionlistener that will be called from your button:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient( new ClientConfig().register( LoggingFilter.class ) );
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemos/rest").path("employees");

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
Response response = invocationBuilder.get();

Employees employees = response.readEntity(Employees.class);
List<Employee> listOfEmployees = employees.getEmployeeList();
```

(from http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-restful-client-examples/#get-list)

Comment: I tried it but it Returns me the whole HTML from the start page instead the XML from the URL I call

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
action=#{yourBean.yourAction}
```

Inside your bean:

```
public void yourAction() {

FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
fc.getExternalContext().redirect("http://...");
fc.responseComplete();

}
```

I'm not sure if it's needed, but also you might wanna set `ajax=false` on `p:commandButton`

Comment: I tryied this already. I don't want to Redirect. I want to Display the Content which is a XML

Comment: display as part of JSF page? display "plain" xml on separate page inside of application? or it is resource outside of application as "http://..." would suggest?

Comment: I tried it and it Redirect me to the Path. I would like to Display get the plain XML, then seperate it in my Java code and Display specific parts of it.